# How can I fix a not-quite-hole in my carpet?

Tags: carpet

The actual strands of my carpet have been pulled up in a half-dollar-sized area, but the base weave that holds it all together is still intact. Is there any way I can repair this without doing a full-on patch? IE, can I "harvest" strands from elsewhere and superglue them there? Or will that still be obvious/undesirable?

Photo of the spot:

[image: Picture of hole in carpet]

Comment: Do you have a carpet scrap? (I always keep carpet scraps for any repairs.) This would be useful even if you do not cut out and replace a piece.

Answer (score 7):

You might try crocheting yarn from elsewhere on the carpet onto the backing. Basically you are pushing loops of yarn through that backing and then pulling them up so they're even with the rest of the yarn. It'll be finicky to get looking right, but should be a nice durable solution if done well.

Alternately, as others have said, cut a scrap and use it to patch that area. If you match the nap direction and keep the edges of the backing material tight when you tape it in place, you should be able to tease the strands up enough to make it look seamless.

Comment: There is no need to pull the strands up "just right".  Get them solidly in place and then use very sharp scissors to cut the top surface to match.

Answer (score 0):

Cut out a piece that matches that size from a scrap or a discreet area (corner of a closet) and glue it on top of the hole.  Trim if needed.